# RestKit fetchRequestForResourcePath returns nil

Tags: ios, restkit

I am using RestKit and am trying to retrieve an object from my local data store with:

```
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[[RKObjectManager sharedManager] mappingProvider] fetchRequestForResourcePath:deviceResourceURI];
```

Unfortunately, this returns `nil` for the `fetchRequest`.

My `deviceResourceURI` is `/api/v1/devices/1`.  I have defined

`[router routeClass:[MSZDevice class] toResourcePath:@"/api/v1/devices/:identifier/"];`

on `[RKObjectManager sharedManager].router`.

I believe all my other Core Data configuration is working.  What am I forgetting?

**Update:**

I'm looking at [RestKit - fetchFromDataStore (cache) issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11756210/restkit-fetchfromdatastore-cache-issue), to see if it is my problem.

**Update:**

Yep -- same problem.  I just don't know how to form the `fetchRequestBlock` portion of the `setObjectMapping:forResourcePathPattern:withFetchRequestBlock:`.  I'm being sent down the `return nil;` path of [this method](https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit/blob/d3cad8df4e0e7ad4d47325c7f02a9fc316aa1ce3/Code/CoreData/RKObjectMappingProvider+CoreData.m#L22).

Answer (score 0):

Answer:

Configure the `RKObjectMappingProvider` with:

```
[objectMappingProvider setObjectMapping:deviceMapping forResourcePathPattern:@"/api/v1/devices/:identifier/" withFetchRequestBlock:^NSFetchRequest*(NSString *resourcePath){
    return [MSZDevice fetchRequest];
}];
```

So simple in retrospect.  Simple enough that I thought this would be the default, introspected return value.